# i can't install codeblocks ID from terminal or ubuntu software centre

Tags: 14.04

while trying install codeblocks ID i found this:

```
mohamed@MoHy:~$ sudo apt-get install codeblocks
[sudo] password for mohamed: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 codeblocks:i386 : Depends: libcodeblocks0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: codeblocks-common:i386 (= 13.12-3) but it is not installable
                   Recommends: gcc:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                               g++:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: gdb:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Try this and post the output in your question: `sudo apt-get install libcodeblocks0:i386`

Comment: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcodeblocks0:i386 : Depends: binutils:i386 (>= 2.14.90.0.7) but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: codeblocks:i386 but it is not going to be installed

Comment: Try a `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` and than `sudo apt -get update` and `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Is this problem: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 101 not upgraded.

Comment: ok, than `sudo apt -get update` and `sudo apt-get install codeblocks`

Comment: ok , i'll try until that : "great thank for you "

Comment: Let me know if it works. I would like to post an answer.

Comment: You'r welcome: Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to your comment that it works now:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt -get update
sudo apt-get install codeblocks
```

That's it! **:)**